# VS 2010 Data Entity Model with database Alias generates connection string on Instance not Alias

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework

I have a Silverlight application using Entity Framework.  When I add a Data Connection in Server Explorer (Visual Studio 2010) I provide the “alias” for my database as the Server Name.  After testing the connection and clicking OK, the connection appears under Data Connections list, but it is not listed under the “alias”.  It appears listed as “ComputerName\Instance.DatabaseName.dbo”.  That in itself is not a problem, but when I generate my entity classes, the connection string that is added to the web.config file lists the “ComputerName\Instance” as the server, rather than the “Alias”.  This is not a problem for me, but when other developers pull my web.config file out of source control they can’t connect to their local copy of the database without changing the web.config file.  It really isn’t a big deal, but it is annoying.  Does anyone know how to get it use the Alias name all the way through?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to modify connection string in web.config after you generate your entity model.

Comment: Yeah, but its still annoying that it doesn't keep the setup you used to create the Data Connection.  Just me whining...  I'll get over it. :)